# Dutch Flag Problem (But do it with Two Colors)

Tags: algorithm, sorting

If there were only two colors needed to be sorted in an array: Red (on the left) & White (on the right), would the following pseudocode make logical sense?

#### Pseudocode:

Pointer *p* & *q*, where *p* points to the first element and *q* points to the last element. *p* can only move right and *q* can only move left in the array.

```c
while (p != q) {
   if (p->color != Red) {
     swap[p,q];
     q--;
   } else {
     p++;
   }
}
```

Comment: Needs more context.

Comment: The full problem seems pretty simple: https://www.educative.io/edpresso/the-dutch-national-flag-problem-in-cpp It uses an _array_ Your pseudocode is a bit unclear. Are `p` and `q` indexes [and/or pointers] into an array?

Comment: Pointer p & q, where p point to the first element and q points to the last element. p can only move right and q can only move left in the array. (Edited original post)

Comment: Does this post help you? In the shared post, the array contains numbers `0` and `1` instead of color `Red` and `White`. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segregate-0s-and-1s-in-an-array-by-traversing-array-once/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that algorithm is correct.

A swap can only result in a yellow value at `q`, and `q` is not decremented as long as no swap happens. By consequence, all values occurring at the *right* side of `q` must be yellow.

Similarly, we can reason that if no swap happens, this means the value at `p` is red, and only in that case is `p` incremented. By consequence, all values occurring at the left of `p` are guaranteed to be red.

This is the loop invariant: all values at the left of `p` are red, and all values at the right of `q` are yellow.

When the loop exits we also know, in addition to the loop invariant, that `p == q`. There are two possibilities: either the value at that position is red or it is yellow. In either case the sorting is correct.